# Store variables in PHP outside of sessions

Tags: php, html, web

In PHP, is there a way to store variables that persist between sessions and even different users accessing the page - that does not use a database, and is fast?

I am creating a marketing a/b split test script.

I wish to store a variable called $Pagecount - that is incremented each time anyone lands on my webpage - and the content shown is dependent on what the variable is.

I am not using MySQL or cookies for this.

Comment: no sessions, no cookies, no database = text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a "text file" will work given appropriate filesystem *write* permissions, if such is allowed there are also other options that may be available. The availability depends on precise PHP build / configuration, as local filesystem access has already been assumed as a premise.

- Use ["sqlite"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php). SQLite is an in-process embedded database that does not require a separate install like MySQL. A benefit SQLite is that it a relational database with a clear (SQL) API.
- Use ["*dbm"](http://php.net/manual/en/dba.requirements.php) (eg. ndbm) which represents a class of in-process key value stores. These *DBM databases provide an API for very fast key-value access even though they lack SQL features.

An advantage of using a database is it removes the need to care about an on-disk format (eg. will it be a single value in a file? an INI file? a JSON document?): the actual problem of storing information can be focused on.